# Linker only sees a portion of libraries in a directory

Tags: g++, cygwin, ld, .so, .a

In my makefile I have:

```
g++ -o Out  Out.o  -I  Headers_Directory -L Libraries_Directory -lFile1 -lFile2
```

In my `Libraries_Directory` I have two files `libFile1.a` and `libFile2.so`

`ld` finds `libFile1.a` but cannot find `libFile2.so`. How that is possible and how can I resolve the issue?

I am compiling in Cygwin and using GNU gcc-g++ compiler.

**A minimalist that regenerates the error:**

Download the Linux Version of Gurobi [here](http://www.gurobi.com/downloads/gurobi-optimizer). Then, install the software using this [instruction](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/quickstart_linux/software_installation_guid.html#section:Installation). You need to activate the software by obtaining a license from [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/quickstart_linux/retrieving_and_setting_up_.html#section:RetrieveLicense). Free academic license for research purpose is available. Finally navigate to the following folder

`installation_directory/gurobi701/linux64/examples/build`

and issue the command `make`. You have to compile on Cygwin with `GNU gcc-g++` compiler.

Comment: You are summarizing what you *think* is true, which makes the
linkage failure mysterious. The answer lies in the difference between
the summary of what you think is true and the details of what is
actually true. So you need to show us the actual makefile,
your actual `make` command, and the actual output of `make`.
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not relevant at build-time.

Comment: @MikeKinghan I have provided a minimalist for regenerating the error.